# Changing format xxxxxxxxxx to xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, string-formatting

I have a textbox in WPF and I need to display text in **xxx-xxx-xxxx** format.

```
<TextBox FontSize="30" Text="{Binding MyString,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="3" MaxLength="10"></TextBox>
```

`MyString` is just property which sets value in TextBox into it for some other logic. Can I do it in XAML itself usng StringFormat?

Comment: How about if you write only `xxx`? How about `xxxx`? How about `xxxxxxx`? Does it allow whitespace? How does that get interpreted?

Comment: xxx  will be like that only. xxxx will be xxx-x and xxxxxxx will be xxx-xxx-x. it won't allow whitespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [MaskedTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) to specify the format of the input.

Example:

```
<wpfx:MaskedTextBox Mask="000-000-0000" />
```

Try [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-maskedtextbox-control/) also.

Comment: I don't prefer adding extra dll's

Answer (score 2):

As an option you could split the text in the code behind (or View Model) and bind each value separately

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0}-{1}-{2}">
            <Binding Path="FirstPart" />
            <Binding Path="SecondPart" />
            <Binding Path="ThirdPart" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: @AliasVarghese They are just bindings though - You could still have one string as the backing field and let the Parts properties return `MyString.Substring(.., ..)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Try the following:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0}-whateverhercomes-andwhateverherecomes">
        <Binding Path="MyString"/>
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
```

Comment: How to identify 3rd and 6th position of MyString and add "-" there?

Comment: Basically I would stick to the answer of @kevchadders. This is an enhanced answer of mine which is, I think, more applicable for your situation.